# SSR in Angular 5 failing when deployed (using ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I made an Angular 5 Project in ASP.NET Core using [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio):

I followed the steps to enable server side rendering and everything is building/working fine on localhost but when deployed over Azure, I get an error and I have no clue what it is (the network tab says Internal Server Error 500, but don't know what's causing it). In the doc I provided, this is the part where I stop:

```
<!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
<BuildServerSideRenderer>true</BuildServerSideRenderer>
```

Here is the error page I'm seeing after deploying:
[image]

I've been able to enable SSR on 3 other different Angluar 5 projects with ASP.NET Core and it works fine even after deployment. Did the exact same thing, followed the exact same steps. I can't seem to find anything related to it online either so I figured I'd ask on here.

I'm not sure what's causing the problem so if anyone wants to request specific pieces of code or files, please do not hesitate to ask. I will try my best to make my question more clear.

Here is my package.json by the way:

```js
{
  "name": "HomeLoanGuys",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css --prod --build-optimizer",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css --prod --build-optimizer",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build --prod -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

One difference between this project and others is that I'm using Angular Material version 5.2.5, not sure if that has anything to do with anything...

Also, I use the commands 'npm run build && npm run build:ssr' to create the dist and dist-server folders. As I've said, everything works fine on localhost (SSR) but I see a 500 error in the network tab, and this error page after deploying. My understanding and experience with Angular and ASP.NET Core is limited as you may be able to tell, so please bear with me.

Update (10/24/2018): 
I'm using jQuery, Angular Material, and performing other DOM manipulations throughout the project. Based on the Microsoft docs, this could cause issues with SSR. I'm not sure if using DOM specific API's is the specific issue, however. Any thoughts?

Comment: When ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production, ASP.NET looks for your client build in the wrong folder. The contents of the `dist/browser` folder should be one level up.